# How to optimise the code considering different input sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I would like to calculate steam properties in most efficient way considering scalar, vector and matrix as two-argument input options. What I am bothered with is that I have to use if blocks with respect to the size of input (scalar, vector or matrix) making the code pretty long. I am simple mechanical engineer quite new to python, any help on how to optimise the code much appreciated. This is the code:

```
from iapws.iapws97 import _Region4
import numpy as np

def h_x(P,x): 
    ''' spec enthalpy in liquid, steam and wet (two-phase flow) regions
    P - pressure in bar
    x - drayness steam fraction [-]
    h - specific heat of wet region returned [kJ/kW]
    '''

    mm = len(np.shape(x))
    if mm == 0:
        h_  = _Region4(P/10,0)['h'] 
        h__ = _Region4(P/10,1)['h'] 
        # return h_ + x * (h__ - h_)
        return h_ + x * (h__ - h_)        
    elif mm == 1:
        return np.array([ _Region4(i/10,0)['h'] + j * ( _Region4(i/10,1)['h'] - _Region4(i/10,0)['h'] ) for i,j in zip(P,x) ])    
    elif mm == 2:
        mmm,nnn = x.shape
        h     = np.ndarray(shape=(mmm,nnn)) #(mm,nn)
        for i in range(mmm):
            for j in range(nnn):
                h_  = _Region4(P[i,j]/10,0)['h']
                h__ = _Region4(P[i,j]/10,1)['h']
                h[i,j]   = h_ + x[i,j] * (h__ - h_)
        return h        
    else:
        print('h_x input must be scalar, vector or 2D matrix!')

# code testing
P = np.array([[.0234,.0193,0.244],[.0244,.0185,0.254]])
x = np.array([[.812,.782,.620],[.912,.882,.820]])
h_x(P,x)
```

Comment: I don't know about efficiency, but code wise ... I'd transform everything in a 2D matrix  ... thous the computation code would be a single block. ```scalar -> [[ scalar ]], [ scalar1, scalar1 ] - > [[[ scalar1, scalar1 ]]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do only one calculation, but in two different ways. You can pull it out and apply it to whatever the function gets as input using the built-in `map`. If that fails, then you have a single (non-iterable) value and you apply your calculation directly.

```
# Define a dummy func to make code work
def _Region4(a, b):
    return {'h': a + 3 * b}

import numpy as np

def calculate(P, x):
    '''
    Spec enthalpy in liquid, steam and wet (two-phase flow) regions
    P - pressure in bar
    x - drayness steam fraction [-]
    h - specific heat of wet region returned [kJ/kW]
    '''
    h_  = _Region4(P/10,0)['h'] 
    h__ = _Region4(P/10,1)['h'] 
    return h_ + x * (h__ - h_) 

def h_x(P,x):
    shape = np.shape(x)
    dimensions = len(shape)
    # Check for wrong input
    if dimensions > 2:
        raise ValueError('h_x input must be scalar, vector or 2D matrix!')
    # Try a general mapping
    try:
        return np.array(list(map(calculate, P.flat, x.flat))).reshape(shape)
    # if it fails then you got a pair of scalar
    except AttributeError:
        return calculate(P, x)

P = np.array([[.023,.23,.05],[.023,.23,.05]])
x = np.array([[.92,.98,.99],[.92,.98,.99]])
print(h_x(P, x))
"""
Out:
    [[2.7623 2.963  2.975 ]
    [2.7623 2.963  2.975 ]]
"""
print(h_x(3, 4))
"""
Out:
    12.3
"""
```

Comment: Thank you, was playing with your code. If inputs are scalars and vectors, e.g. 
P = np.array([.023,.23,.05])
x = np.array([.92,.98,.99])
the code works fine calculates outputs with no error. If inputs are matrices, e.g.
P = np.array([[.023,.23,.05],[.023,.23,.05]])
x = np.array([[.92,.98,.99],[.92,.98,.99]])
It throws the error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
which is the same error I avoided with the two for loops over i and j, making the code pretty long eventually.
Perhaps any other idea? Thank you.

Comment: I found this .flat attribute of numpy vars. So this works well then:
mm,nn = P.shape
hh=np.array(list(map(calculate, P.flat, x.flat))) # .flat variable iterates through all array elements
hh=np.reshape(hh,(mm,nn))

Comment: I think I have figured it out. It seems it can be packed into one line for scalars, vectors and matrices, i.e.

np.array(list(map(calculate,P.flat,x.flat) )).reshape(P.shape)

where .flat flattens the inputs and then .reshape(P.shape) yields the result the same to the input arguments. Important is that arguments (P,x) are defined as np.array(). In this case also scalars have __iter__ attribute and are accepted by the map(), so no len(np.shape(x)) and then np.reshape() lines are needed.

Comment: For me it works fine with 2D-arrays, no need to flatten and reshape. I'll add the full code I am using for you to see.

Comment: I understood why it breaks for you, your solution with the flatten is the correct one. I use a dummy method for the _Region4, but yours does something else to the data and it breaks. Updated the code in the answer with that information, it should work.